# "Training diverged and returned NaN" when fitting a model a second time?

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network

I'm a scikit n00b who's trying out this neural network example:

```
from sknn.mlp import Regressor, Layer

nn = Regressor(
    layers=[
        Layer("Rectifier", units=100),
        Layer("Linear")],
    learning_rate=0.02,
    n_iter=10)
nn.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

found on [0].

I have the appropriate (normalized) dataset (x_train and Y_train) that i'm using. When I execute the nn.fit command, it works once. But any subsequent attempt to re-run it results in a very annoying,

```
  File "1.py", line 39, in <module>
    nn.fit(X, Y.values.ravel())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sknn/mlp.py", line 397, in fit
    return super(Classifier, self)._fit(X, yp, w)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sknn/mlp.py", line 248, in _fit
    raise e
RuntimeError: Training diverged and returned NaN.
```

This error doesn't seem to be documented, so i'm at my wits end. The only way to get it to work again seems to be a re-start of my computer. Has anyone seen this before? does this mean that I need to do some sort of 'cleaning-up' once i'm done fitting?

[0] http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide_model.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meet the similar problem and I tried normalizing my data using scikit-learn’s pipeline, as shown in http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide_sklearn.html#example-pipeline. And I also tried changing the type of output layer from 'Linear' to 'Softmax'.

I am still a novice and I don't know why these methods would help.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,I met the same problem as you were,and solved it by changing"Linear" to “Softmax”.